# List comprehension - need some guidance with discord command/function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def bot(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850828323135160341:
        return
    else:

        lookup = {
    "g.basic": "[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]",
    "g.factory": "[72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1]"
}
        new_args = [lookup.get(arg, arg) for arg in args]
        print(new_args)

        sets = [] # stocking every sets found
        subset = [] #I call a 'set' a pair of brackets
        
        print(new_args)

        for arg in new_args:
            subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
            if ']' in arg: #closing a set
                sets.append(subset)
                subset = [] # creating a new one

        output = [*sets[0]] # number of the first set

        for s in sets[1:]: # looping over every other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):
                output[i] *= s[i] # multiplying the numbers together

        embed=discord.Embed(title="g.stats helper", url="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XPVBiV0ZMtj33m9dHkwBNU6PHrUq0jKW_a810Zbj5qA/edit", description=f":white_check_mark: - Here is your new custom g.stat: \n\n **{output}**", color=0x77AC54)
        channel = client.get_channel(850806578125864981)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Sending !bot [72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1] [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1] works correctly and the bot outputs "[1314.0, 1.4, 0.010000000000000002, 0.7, 4.0, 0.04000000000000001, 1.0, 13.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0]"

But the second I include g.basic or g.factory in the arguments: "!bot [72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1] [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1] g.basic g.factory", the bot gives an error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tqs9.png)

If anyone could not only fix give the answer that will fix this error, but give a somewhat in depth explanation of what they did to solve the error/the meaning of the code they implemented, that would be amazing! I've been struggling for around 7 hours now trying to get this all to work properly.

P.S. You probably won't be much help if you can't interpret the meaning of the code and what it does. I would explain it but it's too much to type out lol :)

Comment: You have double quotes around the list bracket. Which means that the list is a string.

Comment: Also, to fetch any value of the dictionary, you should do logic['g.basic']

Comment: Aslo you added multiple dots and hence it's showing and error. ```subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
          ```. Since you check if there is a dot, it will add the dots and python will throw an error